# Empty result with PHP Curl, But response is exists with json format

Tags: php, xml, curl

I want to extract data from this URL with Php Curl

https://www.tiket.com/ajax/pingFlightSearch?d=CGK&a=DPS&date=2017-08-18&adult=1&child=0&infant=0&airlines=%5B%22LION%22%5D&subsidy=true&page_view=roundseperate

But i got an empty page.

I check to that link and inspect with mozilla network->xhr and there is an content in response tab.

How I can extract the data from that link with php curl?

Here is my code

```
$url = 'https://www.tiket.com/ajax/pingFlightSearch?d=CGK&a=DPS&date=2017-08-18&adult=1&child=0&infant=0&airlines=%5B%22LION%22%5D&subsidy=true&page_view=roundseperate';

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');   
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Host" => "www.tiket.com",
    "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0",
    "Accept" => "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Language" => "en-us,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip, deflate, br",    
    "Content-Type" => "application/cap+xml;charset=utf-8",
    "X-NewRelic-ID" => "UQIGUlJXGwACUFZaAAM=",
    "X-Requested-With" => "XMLHttpRequest",         
    "Connection" => "keep-alive",
    "Pragma" => "no-cache",
    "Cache-Control" => "no-cache"
)); 

$result = curl_exec($cURL);

print_r($result);

curl_close($cURL);
```

I must add 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' at header of that link then response will come out.

[edit header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug0JV.jpg)

Then the response will come out
[response result][2]

Comment: That page also returns an empty response for me - are you sure it doesn't require cookies to be set? The `/ajax/` at the start of the path suggests that it might require a session to already exist.

Comment: Nothing in response..

Comment: I'm forget this one. Add 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' at the header of that link, then response will comeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done a mistake with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER. You set params as Key => Value but it's incorrect. You should set params as values with ":" as the delimiter.

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Host: www.tiket.com",
    "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
    "Content-Type: application/cap+xml;charset=utf-8",
    "X-NewRelic-ID: UQIGUlJXGwACUFZaAAM=",
    "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",         
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache"
));
```

Also I have removed this string to get uncompressed data

```
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
```

Comment: and next time, check the return value of curl_setopt! if you did that, it would've told you already that the setopt failed, and if further had used curl_error() to extract the error, it'd tell you that that the format was invalid. use something like `function ecurl_setopt ($ch , int $option , $value ){
    $ret=curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value);
    if($ret!==true){
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' . return_var_dump ( curl_errno ($ch) ).'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Mate are u sure that this link work? because I inspected the code with mozilla and chrome and the response is empty, and I tried to scrape with a simple php class that i have with curl and the result is empty cuz the link dont have response